# How to create XML file with top 50 records from another XML file in PHP

Tags: php, xml

I have an XML file and has 300 elements. I just want to pull 10 latest records from it and create another XML file.

I will really appreciate if you can just give me some ideas about it?

## PHP

```
$file = '/directory/xmlfile.xml';
if(!$xml = simplexml_load_file($file)){
    exit('Failed to open '.$file);
} else{
    print_r($xml);
    // I want to do some logic here to retrieve top 10 records from file and then create another xml file with 10 records
}
```

## XML Sample Data

```
<data>
    <total>212</total>
    <start>0</start>
    <count>212</count>
    <data>
        <item0>
            <id>123</id>
            <title>abc-test1</title>
            <clientContact>
                <id>111</id>
                <firstName>abc</firstName>
                <lastName>xyz</lastName>
                <email>abc@xyz.ca</email>
            </clientContact>
            <isOpen>1</isOpen>
            <isPublic>1</isPublic>
            <isJobcastPublished>1</isJobcastPublished>
            <owner>
                <id>222</id>
                <firstName>testname</firstName>
                <lastName>testlastname</lastName>
                <address>
                    <address1>test address,</address1>
                    <address2>test</address2>
                    <city>City</city>
                    <state>state</state>
                    <zip>2222</zip>
                    <countryID>22</countryID>
                    <countryName>Country</countryName>
                    <countryCode>ABC</countryCode>
                </address>
                <email>test@test.com</email>
                <customText1>test123</customText1>
                <customText2>testxyz</customText2>
            </owner>
            <publicDescription>
                <p>test info</p>
            </publicDescription>
            <status>test</status>
            <dateLastModified>22222</dateLastModified>
            <customText4>test1</customText4>
            <customText10>test123</customText10>
            <customText11>test</customText11>
            <customText16>rtest</customText16>
            <_score>123</_score>
        </item0>
        <item1>
        ...
        </item1>
        ...
    </data>
</data>
```

Comment: Maybe you can also share a snippet of the xml you want  to read so we get an idea how the structure looks like?

Comment: @codedge I have added a sample XML code

Comment: How is date determined? Is it by position: first ten or last ten `<data>` elements?

Answer (score 1):

Consider [XSLT](https://www.w3.org/Style/XSL/), the special-purpose language designed to transform/manipulate XML to various end uses like extracting top ten `<item*>` tags. No need of `foreach` or `if` logic. PHP maintains an XSLT processor that can be enabled in .ini file [(php-xsl)](http://php.net/manual/en/book.xsl.php).

Specifically, XSLT runs the [Identity Transform](http://www.usingxml.com/Transforms/XslIdentity) to copy document as is then writes a blank template for *item* nodes with position over 10. XML was a bit difficult due to same parent/child `<data>` tags.

**XSLT** *(save as .xsl file which is a well-formed xml)*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">  
        <xsl:copy> 
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="*[substring(name(),1,4)='item' and position() &gt; 10]"/>   

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**PHP**

```
$file = '/directory/xmlfile.xml';

if(!$xml = simplexml_load_file($file)) {
    exit('Failed to open '.$file);    
} else {
    // Load XSLT    
    $xsl = new DOMDocument;
    $xsl->load('/path/to/xsl_script.xsl');

    // Configure transformer
    $proc = new XSLTProcessor;
    $proc->importStyleSheet($xsl);

    // Transform XML source
    $newXML = new DOMDocument;
    $newXML = $proc->transformToXML($xml);

    // Echo new XML tree
    echo $newXML;

    // Save output to file
    $xmlfile = '/path/to/output.xml';
    file_put_contents($xmlfile, $newXML);    
}
```